# Filter signed in user in Firebase Analytics Dashboard

Tags: firebase-analytics, firebase-console

Firebase analytics dashboard offers teh posibility of filter by signed in users. I added the sign_up event to my app and I already have activity for this kind event. Unfortunelly, when I use the filter, there is not information. What do I have to do tell to Firebase that the user is signed id and use the filter.

[image]

Comment: I don't think sign_up  is enough and the login event should be logged as well. It's in the [recommended events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9267735). But I do log 'login' and still this filter results in no result. I don't think the data threshold is applied to sign-in status. If you already have found an answer please share.